# Listar Base de Datos, Usuarios y sus Permisos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Necesito listar a que base de datos esta mapeado cada usuario de mi instancia, así como obtener sus roles y permisos.

Con el siguiente script he conseguido listar los usuarios y su rol, pero en el caso de los permisos no se si haya alguna sentencia similar a SHOW GRANTS [ FOR username ] .Les agradeceré bastante si me pueden dar una mano. Saludos.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.name AS [loginname] ,
        p.type_desc ,
        sp.permission_name
FROM sys.server_principals p
INNER JOIN sys.syslogins s ON p.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions sp ON p.principal_id = sp.grantee_principal_id
WHERE p.type_desc IN ('SQL_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP')
ORDER BY p.name
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo [las respuestas a esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716856/236345) podría ser algo tan sencillo como

```
SELECT 
    class_desc 
  , CASE WHEN class = 0 THEN DB_NAME()
         WHEN class = 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
         WHEN class = 3 THEN SCHEMA_NAME(major_id) END [Securable]
  , USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) [User]
  , permission_name
  , state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions
```

Ya si se quiere algo que devuelva las sentencias listas para usar, otro usuario sugiere algo como

```
select 
    class_desc 
    ,USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) as user_or_role
    ,CASE WHEN class = 0 THEN DB_NAME()
          WHEN class = 1 THEN ISNULL(SCHEMA_NAME(o.uid)+'.','')+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
          WHEN class = 3 THEN SCHEMA_NAME(major_id) END [Securable]
    ,permission_name
    ,state_desc
    ,'revoke ' + permission_name + ' on ' +
        isnull(schema_name(o.uid)+'.','')+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)+ ' from [' +
        USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) + ']' as 'revokeStatement'
    ,'grant ' + permission_name + ' on ' +
        isnull(schema_name(o.uid)+'.','')+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)+ ' to ' +
        '[' + USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) + ']' as 'grantStatement'
FROM sys.database_permissions dp
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysobjects o
    ON o.id = dp.major_id
-- where major_id >= 1  -- ignore sysobjects

order by 
    class_desc desc
    ,USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)
    ,CASE WHEN class = 0 THEN DB_NAME()
         WHEN class = 1 THEN isnull(schema_name(o.uid)+'.','')+OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
         WHEN class = 3 THEN SCHEMA_NAME(major_id) end
    ,permission_name
```

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: @Carolina pero y bien, te sirvió? No te sirvió? Recuerda que si una respuesta te resolvió la pregunta, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que todos sepan que esa respuesta se puede usar

Comment: Si me funciono, gracias